# Linux: Merging rows by the columns having same values

Tags: linux, bash, file, merge

Is there any way to merge rows like:

```
7072;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7079;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7091;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7113;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7128;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7159;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7168;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
```

into just one:

```
7072;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
```

Basically, i need to:
1. Get the numbers(IDs) from the 1st column which have same values on 2,n columns (7072, 7079,7091)
2. Remove duplicates: leave just first one (7072)
there are also other entries like

```
7072;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7079;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7091;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7113;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7128;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7159;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7168;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
```

I need to leave 7072 only.
Finally, it seems like I have to get those numbers and do substitution like

```
sed 's/^id;.*//g'
```

Comment: When you say you want to *Get the numbers(IDs) from the 1st column which have same values on 2,n columns (7072, 7079,7091)* what does that mean exactly? When you "get" them, what do you want to do with them? Store them somewhere? And then when you are displaying the output, are you saying you only want to display the first line that is only different in the id column? Perhaps a more detailed example (input and output) would help.

Comment: I merged several databases, and there are a lot of dublicates having different IDs (since the databases were created by different people and independently). I just want to leave only unique entries and assign an ID to each entry (the best way to do that is just ro leave one of the entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove duplicates based on second column (that is `understand` and `mystify`) you can use the following `awk` script to keep the first copy of the line and filter everything else:

```
awk -F';' '!seen[$2]++' file
```

For the file like the following:

```
$ cat file
7072;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7079;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7091;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7113;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7128;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7159;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7168;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7072;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7079;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7091;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7113;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7128;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7159;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7168;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
```

It will produce an output of (keeping just the first occurrence and filtering everything else)

```
$ awk -F';' '!seen[$2]++' file
7072;understand;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
7072;mistify;-;F;18;IT;MN;2009-03-18 00:00:00
```

We create an array `seen` and use second column as the key. When the line is seen the first time, count of it in our array is zero so we negate it so that the value is 1 and we print it by default. All subsequent times the value will be greater than 0 so we negate that to make it 0 and filter it.

If this is not what you want, please update your question to show what your desired output is based on some sample data.

Comment: If you need to print just the first column then you can modify it by saying `awk -F';' '!seen[$2]++{print $1}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I do not understand your question .. the following will give you the output you ask for:

```
$ uniq -s 4 input.txt |cut -d ";" -f 1

7072
7072
```